# Share internet connection with mulitple Pi's

Tags: pi-3, networking, internet, data-transfer

Let me first start by saying I am very new to this stuff, only about a week into looking at all the options out there. From what I have found Raspberry Pi will be what I need for a project and I know Python, JS, Node.js, ect from my web background.

What I am trying to do is make a bunch of remote sensors (Raspberry PI Zero) either:

1. Transmit data to one hub (Raspberry Pi 3) that is connected to the
   internet via ethernet to make POST requests to my API and the hub
   transmits back to the remote units (if any updates needed)
2. All remote units (Zeros) share the internet connection from the hub
   that is plugged into a router and they make their own POST requests

Basically I am trying to make this plug and play. Where the user just plugs the hub into a router and the remote units can share what they need to the API (no setting up WiFi connections).

Is something like either option possible? Is there any tutorials? I have been searching but haven't round anything. I would imagine this is a common use case.

Comment: The Pi Zero has no built in network connection. Do you mean Zero W.

Comment: @Craig saw a Transmitter module you can use so I assumed the Zero would work. The  Zero W sounds like a better option though if I can share an internet connection from a hub

Comment: @Craig could you use blutooth on the Zero W's to connect to the Pi 3 and use its internet connection from the router? That would be perfect. All I have found was connecting a Pi 3 via wifi and sharing the connection via LAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to provide an answer to my own question, not sure if this is the best way but since no one has a good solution yet, to get the ball rolling what I thought was:

- Turn the Pi 3 "Hub" into a router by using a WiFi usb and connecting
  it to the other router
  (http://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-router/)
- Setup the "Hub" WiFi with a network name and secure password
- Pre program all Zero W "remotes" with that wifi and password so they
  auto connect to the "Hub"
- Then someone else using this set up can just plug the hub in and the
  remotes should have WiFi

This seem correct?

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.